# Syntax Error in MySQL Dynamic Query

Tags: mysql

I've been facing this issue in MySQL since a long time. I've a dynamic query as below in my stored procedure,

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc ()
BEGIN

DECLARE var INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE id VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '0';

WHILE  var <= 10
DO

SET id = CONCAT(id ,',',(SELECT CAST(id AS CHAR) FROM test_client WHERE Rank = var));
SET var = var + 1;

END WHILE;

SET SQL_QUERY = CONCAT('
         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1
         AS
         SELECT *
         FROM test WHERE id IN (',id,');');

SET SQL_QUERY1 = CONCAT('     
         CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2
         AS
         SELECT *
         FROM test1 WHERE id IN (',id,')');

SET @SWV_Stmt = CONCAT(SQL_QUERY,SQL_QUERY1);
PREPARE SWT_Stmt FROM @SWV_Stmt;
EXECUTE SWT_Stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE SWT_Stmt;

END //

delimiter ;
```

When I create and execute this, I get below error,

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 AS SELECT *' at line 5
```

Can anyone please provide a reason and solution for this?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You try to execute 2 queries at once.

Comment: You mean to say I shall take one PREPARE statement for each query?

Comment: @YashwanthAluru Not entirely obvious why you're doing that as a prepared statement either, as there's nothing dynamic about it?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Maybe I wasn't precise in my question. Please see my actual requirement edited above

Comment: @YashwanthAluru you'll still need to prepare and execute them separately (or rewrite to not need the dynamic SQL at all)

Answer (score 2):

That's not a single statement, that is two. The [documentation states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html):

> The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.

Comment: I've been banging my head on the wall on this one for an hour! Thank you so much